# Combinatorics and a special set of subsets of a finite set

Tags: combinatorics

Let $X$ be a finite set of size $n$.

> *Definition.*  A collection of subsets $S\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X)$ is called *Efficient* relative to $X$ iff there is **no** pair of two different subsets $A,B\in S$ for which $A\subset B$.

Denote by $\mathcal{E}(X)$ the set of all efficient sets relative to $X$.

My questions are:

1. Is there a closed form for $\max\limits _{S\in\mathcal{E}(X)}\left|S\right|$ ? (as a function of $n$)
2. Is there a simple way to construct such a set $S\in\mathcal{E}(X)$ that maximizes $|S|$ ?

###### A simple example

In the case of $X=\{1,2,3\}$, the answer to the first question is $3$, and an answer to the second question is either $S_1=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\}$, or $S_2=\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\}\}$.

Comment: That is called https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_theorem

Comment: These are called antichains. Efficient is a new term to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of "efficient" is precisely that of an antichain. (Sidenote: the "relative to $X$" is not needed, since the definition does not involve $X$.)

The questions about the maximum size antichains of the power set of a given set are answered by Sperner's theorem. Note in your examples that $\binom{X}{k}$, the set of all subsets of $X$ of size $k$, the so-called "layers" of the power set / Boolean lattice, form an antichain. The largest antichains of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ are the largest layers, $\binom{X}{\lfloor |X|/2 \rfloor}$ and $\binom{X}{\lceil |X|/2 \rceil}$.